# Set value that comes from an API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, back

I bring from the back an array of objects, where one of those objects has a property called temperament, this property saves a value of type String, example: "Happy, Playful, Friendly". My idea is to place this same String but in the following way: "Happy | Playful | Friendly". From a card component I have tried to do the following

```
/*let temperament2;
if(!createInDb){
     temperament2 = temperament.replaceAll(',','|');
} */
//console.log(temperament)
return(
    <div className="container">
        <img src={image} width="80px" height="80px" alt=""/>
        <h2>{name}</h2>
        <h3>{temperament}</h3>
        <h3>{weight}</h3>
        <h3>{!!createInDb?"true":"false"}</h3>

    </div>
)
```

I have tried to do it directly from the , I have also tried to do it from the back:

```
let dog = dogs.data.map(el =>{
        temp = el.temperament.replaceAll(',','|')
        return{
            id:el.id,
            name:el.name,
            weight:el.weight.metric,
            height:el.height.metric,
            temperament:temp,
            image: el.image.url,
            life_span: el.life_span
        }
    })
```

and neither, I have tried to modify the name property and with success, but I can't do it with the temp property. I don't quite understand where I'm going wrong. I leave the API to where I am making the request
https://api.thedogapi.com/v1/breeds

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue from the sample code (the `temperament.replaceAll(',','|')` successfully replaces commas with bars in the sample string). What will help potential answerers is to provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to check Browser compatibility and/or the Node.js version you have running to see if they support `replaceAll()`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll#browser_compatibility

Alternatively, you can use [`String.prototype.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) to replace the commas:

```js
const newTemperament = temperament.replace(/,/g,' |');
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have an error here:

```
 temp = el.temperament.replaceAll(',','|')
```

Given the code provided, I think it should be:

```
 let temp = el.temperament.replaceAll(',','|')
```

---

Also, you seem to have commented out the replacement? If this is due to it not working, I would point out that it seems that the the new string created by the replacement is not used. Even the commented-out console log uses the original string rather than the mutated one.

I tried the replacement on some static data, it seems to work fine for me with the below code.

```
const dog = [{"weight":{"imperial":"6 - 13","metric":"3 - 6"},"height":{"imperial":"9 - 11.5","metric":"23 - 29"},"id":1,"name":"Affenpinscher","bred_for":"Small rodent hunting, lapdog","breed_group":"Toy","life_span":"10 - 12 years","temperament":"Stubborn, Curious, Playful, Adventurous, Active, Fun-loving","origin":"Germany, France","reference_image_id":"BJa4kxc4X","image":{"id":"BJa4kxc4X","width":1600,"height":1199,"url":"https://cdn2.thedogapi.com/images/BJa4kxc4X.jpg"}}]


const temper = dog[0].temperament.replaceAll(','," |")
return(
    <div className="container">
        <h3>{temper}</h3>
    </div>
)
```